# Sliding Windows for Rows in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data frame, that has about 50000 row, and i want to loop over it, with the loop moving 10 rows each till it get to 50000 row, here is the code.

```
for (i in 1:50000){

  if(df[[1]][i,8] > 1){

    hom <- hom + df[[1]][i,11]
  }else{
    het<-het + het[[1]][i,11]
  }
  score[i] = hom/(hom+het)

}
```

in the code, I am checking, if the condition in column 8 is true or false so that the appropriate function will be applied.
then I am getting the score.
So I basically want to get the score of 10 row each {1-10,2-11,3-12,4-13........49990-50000}

Please, I would be happy if you can help out
thanks

Comment: looks like you need `library(zoo); rollsum(df[[1]], 10)`

Comment: can you please show a small reprodcuible example as some of the index doesn't seem to be correct `df[[1]][i, 8]` here, `df[[1]]` is a vector and doessn't have dim attribute

Comment: @akrun, df is a list, so I am picking the first sublist, which is df[[1]] and in the sublist, it has 11 column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code implements a R function that receives as input a vector and an integer that represents a sliding window of arbitrary size. The function outputs a vector with the mean values of the elements inside every shunk of the window (you can adapt the code to do any other type of computation).

```
# Function that computes an sliding window based on the mean values
compute_mean_feat <- function(vector, window) {
  mean <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(vector)) {
    if (i <= window) {
      sum <- 0
      for (k in 1:i) {
        sum  <- vector[k] + sum
      }
      mean <- c(mean, as.numeric(sum / i))
    } else{
      sum <- 0
      for (j in (i - window + 1):i) 
        sum  <- vector[j] + sum
      }
      mean <- c(mean, as.numeric(sum / i))
    }
  }
  return(mean)
}
```

You can see the result of applying the `compute_mean_feat` function with a sliding window of 10 to a dummy `vector`.

```
# Manual example for testing
window <- 10    
vector <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
compute_mean_feat(vector, window)
```

For a data frame, you just need to apply this function to the desired column and it will give you the sliding window vector for its rows.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked, but, it seems a bit slow, whenever i use it to iterate through row of over 150,000. Thanks alot, it worked like runmean, as i wanted it to work